# app crashes on changing layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a linearlayout in scrollview

```
    <ScrollView 
       android:id="@+id/scrollID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    >
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/showInfoLayout"> 
      </LinearLayout>
                 </ScrollView>
```

and in code i changes scrollView width and height than app crashes my code of change is

```
     @Override
             public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                 routeScrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                 return true;
             }
```

the double tap event works fine and logcat is as following
[image]

Comment: Try using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. It's a class cast exception in the `LinearLayout` class, which has its own `LayoutParams` (a subclass of `ViewGroup`'s ones), so I'd suspect this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Your LinearLayout's layout_height should wrap content

2) Replace ViewGroup.LayoutParams by (TypeOfScrollViewParent).LayoutParams